# Does having a server in another country slows down your website?

Tags: dns, web-hosting

I have a server in Texas USA (hostgator), my domain (.be) is bought at godaddy and people open my website in Belgium (West-Europe).

Is it better to have a server in Belgium?
The price for the same thing I get with hostgator will be times 3.

Comment: there are only important two issues: service and cost; location of your server is only important for geopolitical reasons. if you get a better value (high service to cost ratio) going with a server in Belgium, do it.

Comment: thanks, no a server in Belgium would be up to 3 times more expensive as a server in the USA, so I think I'm good with hostgator

Comment: ah i read that wrong when i wrote that. it's fine either way, i tend to speak in conditionals.

Comment: Yes, it is better to have a server at Belgium or you can find another provider that are located close to you. Yeah, I mean please try to find European server. I would recommend for you HostForLife.eu, I find it on Microsoft site and their server located in Amsterdam. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to have your server in Belgium. People accessing your website from Belgium will have low latency accessing your website and they will experience faster loading of your website.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Website response time of various locations]

These are the response times of my website at various locations. My website server location is US and my location is India. So, this test proves that if you have server in same location, it will have much higher loading speed as compared to if you have server in some other country.

Comment: how do you measure this?

Comment: there are lots of sites on internet, you can search for "test website server speed". The one I have used is bitcatcha.com.